# Redirecionar qualquer URL extensão html para uma página específica

Tags: apache, htaccess, ubuntu

Por favor, estou com uma dúvida em .htaccess (ou apache).

Preciso redirecionar qualquer url que contenha extensão **.html** ou **.htm** para uma url específica. Exemplo:

- dominio.com/teste.html -> dominio.com/pagina
- dominio.com/teste123.htm -> dominio.com/pagina

**Segue o atual `.htacces:`**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Olá, experimenta isto - [URL's Amigáveis](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1a0fwaW7GZv3kd_jNMV_j56tiefhwVZk_CgorLH0RiMA/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para este redirecionamento é necessário ter o módulo `mod_rewrite` ligado.
Para ligar o mesmo, use este comando:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart # para reiniciar o servidor
```

Insere o seguinte conteúdo no `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^pagina$ - [L] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html?$ pagina [L] 

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

**Nota:**  para isto funcionar, tem de ter a opção `AllowOverride All` na configuração do diretório(`<Directory>...</Directory>`) do vhost em vigor.

Comment: Olá Tim, obrigado. Não deu certo. Estou usando dentro do Wordpress. O AllowOverrride All já estava configurado. Ele ignora a linha, ou seja, não está redirecionando, cai direto num 404.

Comment: Talvez porque já tem .htaccess padrão configurado. Verifique se não há outras regras RewriteRule antes no seu .htaccess ou na configuração do apache.

Comment: Coloquei no post original o atual .htaccess

Comment: Editei o conteúdo do .htaccess da minha resposta conforme a situação. Assim deve funcionar.

Comment: Obrigado! É isso mesmo.

Comment: Apenas para constar, esse comando não deixa entrar no /wp-admin do WP.